# How to Sign Android app Bundle with azure pipeline

Tags: android, azure, azure-pipelines

How to Sign Android App Bundle with the azure pipeline,

The documentation is available only signing APK 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/android-signing?view=azure-devops

when I try to sign aab with the above task I am getting below error

Error: Failed to deduce min API Level: APK does not contain AndroidManifest.xml. Please specify --min-sdk-version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem with signing the Android app bundle, Right now we fixed this issue with the signing app bundle in the `Azure Build Pipeline` instead of signing Android app bundle from the `Azure Release pipeline` through `jarsigner`.

Comment: Can you share the command you used for signing the app bundle

Comment: jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/android.keystore -storepass KEYSTOREPASSWORD $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab KEYSTOREALIAS

Comment: @BHAR4T You can use secure files and pipeline variables to make the command more secure.

e.g.
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore $(KeyStoreFile.secureFilePath) -storepass $(KeyPassword) -keypass $(KeyPassword) $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/*.aab $(KeyAliass)

In the above command KeyPassword and KeyAlias are pipeline variables and KeyStoreFile is available via Download Secure File task.

Comment: Is it okay to push the keystore file to a repository? My repo is private and accessed by internal dev only.

Comment: @EvanGunawan You should never push your keystore file to version control.

Answer (score 9):

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69835335/168510

Change the apkFiles to `**/*.aab` and pass the algorithms, `-sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256` as jarsignerArguments.

Like this:

```
- task: AndroidSigning@2
  inputs:
     apkFiles: '**/*.aab' 
     jarsign: true 
     jarsignerKeystoreFile: 'pathToYourKeystoreFile'
     jarsignerKeystorePassword: '$(jarsignerKeystorePassword)'
     jarsignerKeystoreAlias: '$(yourKeystoreAlias)'
     jarsignerKeyPassword: '$(jarsignerKeyPassword)'
     jarsignerArguments: '-sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256'
     zipalign: true
```

Comment: When adding the task from the list in devops you get AndroidSigning@3 by default. Note that you have to change it from 3 to 2 in order to get the jar version.

Answer (score 4):

> How to Sign Android app Bundle with azure pipeline

AFAIK, you could sign Android app Bundle from command line:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore xample.jks bundle.aab keystoreAlias
```

The `jarsigner.exe` is in the `bin` folder of your java JDK install (Java SE), so we could get it by:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\jarsigner.exe
```

So, we could use the command line task to invoke the `jarsigner.exe` to sign Android app Bundle in the Azure pipeline.

Check [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50560045/sign-android-app-bundle-from-command-line) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This command is giving me the below error -- jarsigner: unable to open jar file: app-release.aab