# Signing an Android bundle on Azure pipelines with jarsigner fails with error " Please specify alias name "

Tags: android, xamarin.android, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline that builds an android app well.
I now want to sign the android active bundle created by this pipeline, so that I can distribute it.
The problem is, I have to sign it. I use this yaml command to sign it

```
- task: CmdLine@2
displayName: 'Signing and aligning AAB file(s) **/*.aab'
inputs:
  script: 'jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore 
   releaskey.keystore -storepass $(KeystorePassword) -keypass $(KeystorePassword) 
   /Users/runner/work/1/s/Platforms/MobileApp.Android/obj/
   Release/android/bin/mobileapp.aab'
```

Here is the final command ran in the pipeline : `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore releasekey.keystore -storepass *** -keypass *** /Users/runner/work/1/s/Platforms/MobileApp.Android/obj/Release/android/bin/mobileapp.aab`

But the problem is that, at the end I get the error:

> Please specify alias name

I went to the jarsigner [documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html), and it state that "The aliases are defined in the keystore specified by -keystore or the default keystore."
But though I precise a keystore, the build fails at this point.

Comment: You can try to add a alias  for your keystore .You can refer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405181/how-to-sign-android-app-bundle-with-azure-pipeline .

Comment: Thankyou very much. Doing that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add a alias for your keystore .

For example:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore xample.jks bundle.aab keystoreAlias
```

For more,you can refer to this thread:

[How to Sign Android app Bundle with azure pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405181/how-to-sign-android-app-bundle-with-azure-pipeline)