# Update existing app on appstore with a webapp that has a different codebase and project

Tags: android, ios, web

Thanks for giving this a read. I have an existing React Native app but after years of going back and forth with the company who helped build it, we decided that the mobile site still offers all the best features for a good app. So I decided I will make a web app which is fairly simple to do with loads of companies out there offering the online service. What I don't want is for my users to download a completely different app. I know there is a way to push out a new app build on a different codebase if you consider things like certificates and for Android somehow connect the same keystore credentials. Does anyone have helpful documentation for this? Or a web app company that will help with this? I have all the certificates, firebase files, etc etc

Thanks again!

I tried to do it myself and to explain it to support. I think the language differences is what make it hard.

Comment: Probably related: [Sign Android App Bundle from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50560045/295004)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can replace the codebase with whatever technology that works for Android / iOS.

As I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64005603/how-to-update-a-flutter-app-on-already-published-native-android-using-java-app-i/64005706#64005706), an app has to meet the following three requirements to be an elligible update for an exisiting app:

1. The application ID must be identical.
2. The version number must be greater than the version number of the previously released app.
3. The app must be signed with the same signing key as before.

Besides that, it doesn't matter if you create your app with Kotlin/Java (Android), Objective-C / Swift (iOS), Flutter, Xamarin, React Native, Cordova or any other technology.

Comment: Thanks for this. I believe I read this and tried to follow it. The thing with the web apps are, they generate the already build file. 

Let's take Android for a second. So how do I add the keystore details to an already build aab package?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. After some extensive research I settle upon a site called App My Site. They seem to be able to do the migration successfully. I'm sad that I need to result in basically downgrading my app in order to get it to work properly. But the Buddyboss app built on react native is not an adequate solution for any business hoping to build a successfully community app. Their roadmap is almost half a decade old and not being honored.
Thanks again!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).